# How to check AutoCompleteTextView if it contains text?

Tags: java, android, autocomplete

I have two AutoCompleteTextView in fragments that user should fill. Then these two string values must be sent to other activity otherwise (if it doesn't filled) you should see a toast. I tried to implement it but it doesn't work:

```
public void onFindPathClick(View view) {
    String originAddress = OriginPlaceFragment.mAutoPlaceSearch.getText().toString();
    String destinationAddress = DestinationPlaceFragment.mAutoPlaceSearch.getText().toString();

    Intent intent = new Intent(SimpleTabsActivity.this, MapsActivity.class);
    if ((originAddress != "") && (!originAddress.equals(null)) && (destinationAddress != "") && (!destinationAddress.equals(null))) {
        intent.putExtra(ORIGIN_ADDRESS, originAddress);
        intent.putExtra(DESTIN_ADDRESS, destinationAddress);
        startActivity(intent);
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Fill \"from\" and \"to\" fields", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: what happens, if it gives a exception. put it to the question, and also I hope onFindPathClick is bound to a event ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of checking (originAddress != ""), use the isEmpty() method.

```
public void onFindPathClick(View view) {
String originAddress = OriginPlaceFragment.mAutoPlaceSearch.getText().toString();
String destinationAddress = DestinationPlaceFragment.mAutoPlaceSearch.getText().toString();

Intent intent = new Intent(SimpleTabsActivity.this, MapsActivity.class);
if (!originAddress.toString().isEmpty() && !destinationAddress.toString().isEmpty()) {
    intent.putExtra(ORIGIN_ADDRESS, originAddress);
    intent.putExtra(DESTIN_ADDRESS, destinationAddress);
    startActivity(intent);
} else {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Fill \"from\" and \"to\" fields", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
}
```